# MongoDB not starting properly on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

```
root@HangoutRoot:/Bot# sudo systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-06-08 08:57:25 PDT; 5s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 2241 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=48)
 Main PID: 2241 (code=exited, status=48)

Jun 08 08:57:25 HangoutRoot systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
```

That's what I get when I check the status of the mongodb server using `sudo systemctl status mongod`

Comment: Try sudo service mongod start.

Comment: Didn't work```● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-06-08 09:15:09 PDT; 14s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 2639 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=48)
 Main PID: 2639 (code=exited, status=48)

Jun 08 09:15:09 HangoutRoot systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.```

Comment: See what `journalctl -xe` is saying about it. Also, if exists go read `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`, and please post the error messages you find in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command : `sudo systemctl enable mongod`

After this:
 run this command

`sudo service mongod restart`

If this still do not work I think reinstalling mongo would be a better solution.

To re-install mongo follow the the process of accepted answer from this link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/884541/cant-start-mongodb-service